# How do I get the last row of a bound WPF Datagrid to notify View Model when the SelectedItem Changes?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, selecteditem

This is my first post - I welcome any advice on how I post questions should I need it.

I have a WPF `DataGrid` that has `ItemsSource` bound to a property called OrderDetails(List Of OrderDetails) and `SelectedItem` bound to a property called CurrentOrderDetail.

Inside the CurrentOrderDetail property I call a method that does a calculation.  The method that does the calculation loops through the OrderDetails property and multiplies two members of each OrderDetail that belongs to that list to produce a total cost.  That method just simply updates another property that a text box is bound to on the form.

This all works great - until I get to the last row of the `DataGrid`.  Basically the user starts at the first row, clicks into the Invoiced field and enters a quantity and presses enter, which selects the next row.  The `SelectedItem` changes and therefore updates the CurrentOrderDetail - calling calculate.  This works!  The user repeats the process, everything calculating OK, until the last record in the `DataGrid` is hit.  When the user hits Enter to end the edit on the Invoiced cell, the calculate method is never called - because the `SelectedItem` has not changed and therefore the CurrentOrderDetail property is never updated.

I like standards and since I've recently moved to WPF/Silverlight and MVVM, I've not looked back.  As such, I'm trying to keep this app the same way.

I guess I need to force something to trigger the `SelectedItem` changing.  I've thought about hooking into events in the View and simply forcing a navigate, but that just seems a bit ugly to me.  There's gotta be a better solution.  I've spend two days out here and other forums as well as trying several ideas of my own, none of which work.

I could just ask the user to navigate to another row to trigger the property notification, but I'd rather not.

Here's just the XAML for the `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid Name="grdData" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="5,5,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OrderDetails, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentOrderDetail, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderThickness="3" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>   
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Part}" Header="Wyandot Part #" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SupplierPartNumber}" Header="Supplier Part #" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=UnitPrice, StringFormat=c}" Header="Price" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Account}" Header="Account" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=UDF5, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Invoiced" IsReadOnly="False" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And the snippets from my View Model that are pertinent.

```
Private m_orderDetails As List(Of OrderDetail)
Public Property OrderDetails As List(Of OrderDetail)
    Get
        Return m_orderDetails
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of OrderDetail))
        m_orderDetails = value
        InvokePropertyChanged("OrderDetails")
    End Set
End Property

Private m_currentOrderDetail As OrderDetail
Public Property CurrentOrderDetail As OrderDetail
    Get
        Return m_currentOrderDetail
    End Get
    Set(value As OrderDetail)
        m_currentOrderDetail = value
        InvokePropertyChanged("CurrentOrderDetail")
        Calculate()
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub Calculate()
    Dim total As Decimal = 0

    For Each detail As OrderDetail In OrderDetails
        total += detail.UnitPrice * detail.UDF5
    Next

    PoTotal = CStr("$" & total.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered using IObservable? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like your calculation is happening on the wrong changed event.  I would have the `OrderDetail` value property that the user is updating trigger a property changed event and use that to update my total.

It is a little more work to subscribe to each property changed event of each `OrderDetail`, but that is what you really care about.  I would probably use an `ObservableCollection<OrderDetail>` and then in the `Collectionchanged` event wire up the necessary listeners.

Comment: Responding to both, I've thought of that, but what I get back from Entity (left that part out - sorry - using LINQ to Entity) is an  OrderHeader object (Master) which contains the ICollection(Of OrderDetail) (Details).  I guess I could iterate ICollection and add them to an observable collection.  I would just need to push those changes back to the OrderHeader's IColleciton before saving

Comment: I feel your pain.  I find myself wrapping perfectly good EF objects all the time because of this or similar reasons.  But in the end, having the extra layer of separation almost always makes my life easier.